# Trying to teach myself futures ,have some queries

Tags: futures

I understand the basic idea of futures when it comes to like hedging and companies using it to manage costs, however when it comes to trading them I am completely lost.

All i know is that in a market you can buy a futures contract or one is made for you, or you are paired with someone who is shorting, (this is you believing the underlying asset will go up), you can also short a contract when this happens you are paired up with someone who is longing the contract or a contract is created for you.

But is there no way for you to receive a contract from someone else like you do when your longing a contract? Furthermore if one party decides to close out their contract how would they go about doing this, if you are longing I know you can sell out your position to someone else but you can also cancel out your contract, (I have no idea how this happens or makes sense), and if you're shorting and want to pull out how does buying a futures contract cancel you out?

Not sure if this made much sense?

Answer (score 1):

When you enter in to a futures contract (typically called "buying" or "selling" even though you aren't really buying or selling anything yet - you're just entering into one side of a contract), a new contract is created between you (A) and another willing participant (B). If that participant is *already* in a contract with another party (C) and is closing their position (e.g. they are long and are closing their long position), then the B-C contract is cancelled and a new contract between you and C is created.

This is all done transparently by the exchange. You never know who is on the other end of your contract (and it can change if they close out as described above), and settlement is handled completely by the exchange through a clearing house.

So you can absolutely "receive" a contract from another party whether you are going long or short if they are closing out their existing position.  Note that you will still enter in to a contract at the current futures price; any difference in settlement price between the existing contract and the new contract will be handled by the exchange.

> if one party decides to close out their contract how would they go about doing this

The only way to get out of a futures contract is to enter into an opposing contract, and pay whatever profit/loss you realize by doing so. For example. If you "buy" an Oil future at $100 but then decide to close that out, the only way is to "sell" an equivalent oil future. If the price of oil has dropped to $90, you have to pay (through the exchange) $10 per barrel for your realized loss.

There is no way to "cancel" a contract that you are in other than by offsetting it. I have heard of cases where participants negotiate to avoid physical settlement (i.e. not actually delivering the commodity but cash settling) but I do not know if or how that actually happens. Most futures contracts are sold before expiry; very few actually physically settle.